# Using Equirectangular projection in react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I want to draw a map using Equirectangular projection in the react-leaflet.
The reaction-leaflet used CRS, which supports Equirectangular projection, but the image of the desired map is not connected and truncated.
The coordinates also do not appear in the correct position.

```
          <MapContainer
            center={[0, 0]}
            zoom={2}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
            zoomControl={false}
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
            minZoom={2}
            maxZoom={5}
            doubleClickZoom={false}
            crs={CRS.EPSG4326}
            >
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are rendering an Open Streets Map correct? I believe that the Open Steets Map is supposed to use the `EPSG:3857` projection. Open Street Map tiles use a coordinate system based on the wgs84 datum (ESPG 3857). I don't think you can project any map on any projection. You can refer to this [GIS.stackexchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet) which explains the differences.

I just tried it on a demo leaflet map that I have and got the same thing. [image: same thing].

`<MapContainer ref={mapRef} center={[lat, lon]} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={true} crs={CRS.EPSG4326}   id="leaflet-container">`

Comment: I used CRS4326 to use "Equirectual projection".
The program I'm trying to create now is difficult to check the right scope by using "Mercator projection".
Therefore, we will use CRS4326, but we have not solved the problem of rendering beyond the map.